# Spring cloud gateway and Keycloak invalid credentials

Tags: spring-security, oauth, keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a set up with a Spring Cloud Gateway service that redirect the requests from my frontend apps to my backend services. I want some of those requests to be authenticated, so I have a keycloak server also running. Both services runs inside docker and share a docker network. I have tried to run the Spring cloud gateway outisde the docker network and it works fine, I am able to login using the keycloak form, but once I set up the docker setup, when I try to login with the correct credentials I get this page as result, the IP is my wsl ip, where the docker is running and also used in the configuration as keycloak-host.

[image: invalid credentials]

This is my application.yml configuration:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin Access-Control-Request-Headers
        - SaveSession
        - TokenRelay=
      routes:
        - id: resource
          uri: ${postman-mock}
          predicates:
            - Path=/resource

  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: ${keycloak-host}/realms/${realm}
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username #here also tried with email
        registration:
          keycloak:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: ${client-id}
            client-secret: ${client-secret}
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope:
              - openid
              - profile
              - email
              - roles
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: ${keycloak-host}/realms/${realm}
```

In the keycloak configuration I have tried multiple Valid redirect URIs & Valid post logout redirect URIs
but currently both have `*` set.

Any idea of the possible issue?

Comment: Maybe the `client-id` and `client-secret` are not set correctly in your Spring Docker container

Comment: In the sample I've used variables, but I tried hardcoding them